# Can I use different views for children in a ExpandableListView using a SimpleCursorTreeAdapter?

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I would like to use a database-backed ExpandableListView where the child items should be shown in one of two different views depending on a database field.

(if an item has the flag "done" set in the database, it should be displayed in gray, else it should be displayed in white.)

This is how I bind the ExpandableListView to the database:

```
dbAdapter = new TasksDbAdapter(this);
dbAdapter.open();
c = dbAdapter.getTaskGroupsInList(listId);
startManagingCursor(c);
    dbTreeAdapter = new TaskListTreeAdapter(
            getApplicationContext(), 
            c, 
            listId, 
            R.layout.listgroupitem, 
            R.layout.listitem, 
            new String[] { 
                TaskDbAdapter.KEY_TASKTYPE_NAME }, 
            new int[] { 
                R.id.groupName }, 
            new String[] { 
                TaskDbAdapter.KEY_LISTITEMS_AMOUNT, 
                TaskDbAdapter.KEY_UNITS_NAME, 
                TaskDbAdapter.KEY_TASK_NAME }, 
            new int[] { 
                R.id.tvItemAmount, 
                R.id.tvItemUnit, 
                R.id.tvItemName });
```

This is the getChildView method of the Adapter:

```
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vReturnView = null;
        Cursor cGroupsTemp = dbAdapter.getGroups(listId);
        if (cGroupsTemp.moveToPosition(groupPosition))
        {
            long groupId = cGroupsTemp.getLong(cGroupsTemp.getColumnIndex(KEY_PRODTYPE_ID));
            Cursor cChildsTemp = dbAdapter.getChildren(listId, groupId);
            if (cChildsTemp.moveToPosition(childPosition))
            {
                long childId = cChildsTemp.getLong(cChildsTemp.getColumnIndex(KEY_LISTITEMS_ID));
                boolean bought = cChildsTemp.getInt(cChildsTemp.getColumnIndex(KEY_DONE)) > 0;
                LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                if (bought)
                {
                    vReturnView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listenlistitemdone, null);
                } else {
                    vReturnView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listenlistitem, null);
                }
            }
        }
        return vReturnView;
    }
```

Unfortunately, the two different views are not shown correctly.
Does anyone know why?
Do the two views have to belong to a common ViewGroup?
I did not find any methods like getViewTypeCount() or getItemViewType() in the Adapter.
Are they not needed for this Adapter?
Do the elements in the two Views have to have the same IDs (as the adapter only binds one single ID to a database column)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe you can do that since (as you guess) the layouts would have to have duplicate ids, and I don't think that's allowed.

Instead of trying to use two different layouts, why don't you use a single one and then override the `bindChildView` from the `ExpandableListAdapter` and change the colors in there?

A small sample from one of my projects (edited to condense it to a managable block):

```
    protected void bindChildView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor,
            boolean isLastChild) {

        TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.ListItem1);
        TextView qty = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.ListItem3);

        name.setTextColor(GroceryApplication.shoplistitem_name);
        qty.setTextColor(GroceryApplication.shoplistitem_qty);

        name.setText(cursor.getString(2));
        qty.setText(cursor.getString(1));

        if (cursor.getInt(5) == 1) {
            name.setPaintFlags(name.getPaintFlags()
                    | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
            qty.setPaintFlags(qty.getPaintFlags()
                    | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
            view.setBackgroundResource(R.color.purchased);
        } else {
            name.setPaintFlags(name.getPaintFlags()
                    & ~Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
            qty.setPaintFlags(qty.getPaintFlags()
                    & ~Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
            view.setBackgroundResource(R.color.black);
        }
    }
}
```

The above code uses a flag in the db which will cause the app to either change the background to gray and the text to be strikethrough style or have the background color be my default color and cancel the strikethrough text.